# Turn off console logging in Google App Engine Application

Tags: google-app-engine, java.util.logging

I have an application running on the Google App Engine (GAE) v1.8.2. I have been using java.util.logging. My classes have the logger defined as:

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

My appengine-web.xml has these lines:

```
  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
```

The logging.properties files contains these lines:

```
# A default java.util.logging configuration.
# (All App Engine logging is through java.util.logging by default).
#
# To use this configuration, copy it into your application's WEB-INF
# folder and add the following to your appengine-web.xml:
# 
# <system-properties>
#   <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
# </system-properties>
# WARNING , INFO, SEVERE, OFF
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
# Set the default logging level for all loggers to WARNING
.level = OFF
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=OFF
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

However, I still continue to see the INFO logging from my code in the browser console. How do I turn off the console logging off completely?

Update: Contents of my appengine-java-sdk-1.8.2/config/sdk/logging.properties file:

```
# Logging configuration file for Google App Engine tools.

# Specify the handlers to create in the root logger
# (all loggers are children of the root logger)
# The following creates the console handler
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# Set the default logging level for the root logger
.level = INFO

# Set the default logging level for the datanucleus loggers
DataNucleus.JDO.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Persistence.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Cache.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.MetaData.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.General.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Utility.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Transaction.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Datastore.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.ClassLoading.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Plugin.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.ValueGeneration.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Enhancer.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.SchemaTool.level=WARNING

# FinalizableReferenceQueue tries to spin up a thread and fails.  This
# is inconsequential, so don't scare the user.
com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue.level=WARNING
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue.level=WARNING

# We assume that people will generally want to see this message, even
# if they override the root level to WARNING.  If they really want to
# turn it off, they can always override this level as well.
com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.level=INFO
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm that the `LogManager` is using your `logging.properties`. An easy way to test that would be to change the `ConsoleHandler` formatter from `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter` to `java.util.logging.XMLFormatter` then see if your output is xml.  If it is xml then you could try commenting out the `handlers=` line.  If the output is still from the `SimpleFormatter` then:

1. Check the path to the logging.properties.
2. Ensure a `SecurityManager` is not preventing changes to logging.
3. Write code to walk all of the loggers and output the classname of all attached handlers.  Then update your `logging.properties` to disable any other handlers that might be writing to the console.
4. Write code to walk all of the loggers and disable and all console handlers.
5. <strike>System.out.close(); System.err.close();</strike>
6. <strike>new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out).close(); new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.err).close();</strike>

Comment: I still see the output from SimpleFormatter. My logging.properties file is under WEB-INF. How do I check #2, #3 and #4? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DFB #2 System.getSecurityManager().checkPermission.  #3 & #4 Use the LogManager to get all the logger names then ask for each logger by name.

Comment: Which permission should I check for? I can't use LogManager in GAE. It says LogManager is not supported by GAE's Java runtime environment. Throughout my code, I have only info and warning logging (logger.info("something") and logger.warn("something")). It seems like it's not using my logging.properties at all. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Check for 'new LoggingPermission("control")'.  I agree that it seems like it is not using that at all.  Makes me lean towards #1.  There must be an alternate way to specify the path. I.E. "./WEB-INF/logging.properties"

Comment: I just noticed that it does switch to XML format in Eclipse's Console, but in Chrome's console, it remains in Simple format.

Comment: I have just updated the post with the contents of the default appengine's logging.properties. Changing the level in that file also doesn't make any difference in the Browser's console logging. In my class files, if I do logger.getLevel(), it returns null. But if I do logger.setLevel(Level.OFF), it does turn off logging for that class specifically (as expected). But I'm trying to find a way to turn off logging for all classes in my application.

Comment: Might have to set '.useParentHandlers=false' for each of your loggers.